# IDE for building extensions in TYPO3

Tags: ide, typo3

Is there any IDE for developing an extension in TYPO3 V 6.0 + ?
I'm using extension builder to develop extensions and FE plugins

Comment: http://wiki.typo3.org/PHP_Editors_/_IDE_for_TYPO3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use every IDE that supports Namespaces (php 5.3 feature) to get the best results in code completion and type hinting. I prefer PHPStorm but I also used PHPEclipse a while ago.